# Define a function f based on function g such that f doesn't change if g changes later

Tags: function-construction, core-language

I would like to do something like

```
f[x_]:=g[x];
```

But I don't want that definition of f to change if the definition of g changes later.

How can I proceed?

Comment: `f[x_] =g[x]` ?

Comment: oooh well. Sorry for my question it seems that I still don't know some basics of language :D. I thought we could only create functions with the := symbol

Comment: @LLlAMnYP If `g[x_?NumericQ] = x` then `f` will change if `g` changes

Comment: Not so basic, especially if x is allready defined and you don't want to use the definition of x. I think this latest problem has been treated in a post.

Comment: I can't find the post I mentioned just above. Among the possibilities one can 1) of course, change de variable name 2) use a formal parameter 3) use `Block[{x},f[x_]:=g[x]]`, though I don't know if 3) is a good practise.

Answer (score 3):

If `g[x]` evaluates to what you need, you can define `f` with either `=` or `:=`:

```
f[x_] = g[x];
(f[x_] := #) &[g[x]]
```

If a single evaluation of `g` doesn't return all that matters, assign it to another symbol whose definitions are to be kept fixed:

```
  UpValues[g2] = UpValues[g]   /. g -> g2;    DownValues[g2] = DownValues[g]   /. g -> g2;
Attributes[g2] = Attributes[g] /. g -> g2;       Options[g2] = Options[g]      /. g -> g2;
 SubValues[g2] = SubValues[g]  /. g -> g2;  FormatValues[g2] = FormatValues[g] /. g -> g2;
```

and replace `g` by `g2` in your definition for `f`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple idea of how you can explore the use of functions:

```
g[x_?NumericQ] := x
f[x_] := g[x]
```

**Testing:**

```
f[x]
```

> g(x)

```
f[2]
```

> 2

```
g[x]
```

> g(x)

```
g[2]
```

> 2